# Is it better to call two INSERT/UPDATE queries or to call one with trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a question regarding MySQL triggers as Google gave me no usable results.

Let's imagine situation I have to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a row into MySQL table while this procedure is also logged/audited into different table, e.g. with two queries for `INSERT` I would do:

```
INSERT INTO `cars` (`brand`, `type`, `year`) VALUES ('Audi', 'A6', 2013);
```

then receive the new row's ID and perform insert into the log table:

```
INSERT INTO `cars_log` (`car_id`, `brand`, `type`, `year`, `action`, `date`) VALUES (1954, 'Audi', 'A6', 2013, 'insert', NOW());
```

Instead of this solution I could also go with only one `INSERT`/`UPDATE` query (into `cars`) and define triggers listening for `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE` that would insert my log data automatically.

The question is: **From the performance point of view what is better solution?**

Additional questions:

- Is the behaviour (performance issue) same through all relational DBMS?
- Is this performance difference (if any) remarkable even with low number of `INSERT`/`UPDATE` queries or only when the load gets higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a trigger will not affect the execution speed significantly -- in the end, the database system is executing the same operations.

But if you are sure that every `INSERT` mandates the updates then triggers are a great way to 
**ensure database integrity**, so by all means do it.

Put in other words - triggers are the way to go for implementing any kind of tracking of database changes. However, you need to be aware of what happens under the hood when you use triggers.

According to [MySQL Stored Procedure Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100892), page 256 under the head "Trigger Overhead" says the following:

> It is important to remember that, by necessity, triggers **add
>   overhead to the DML** statement to which they apply. The actual amount
>   of overhead will depend upon the nature of the trigger, but --- as all
>   `MySQL` triggers execute `FOR EACH ROW` --- the overhead can rapidly
>   accumulate for statements that process large numbers of rows. You
>   should therefore avoid placing **any expensive** SQL statements or
>   procedural code in triggers.

An expanded explanation of trigger overhead is given on pages 529-531. The concluding point from that section states the following:

*Since the trigger code will execute once for every row affected by a `DML` statement, the trigger can easily become the most significant factor in `DML` performance. Code inside the trigger body needs **to be as lightweight as possible** and -- in particular -- any SQL statements in the trigger should be supported by indexes whenever possible.*

Another thing when using triggers - when it comes to audit logging, please be aware of what you log data into. I say this because should you choose to log to a `MyISAM` table, each `INSERT` into a `MyISAM` table **produces a full table lock during** the `INSERT`.

This can become a serious bottleneck in a high-traffic, high-transaction environment. Additionally, if the trigger is against an `InnoDB` table and you log changes in `MyISAM` from within the trigger, this will secretly disabled `ACID` compliance (i.e., reduce block transactions to auto-commit behavior), which cannot be rolled back.

Comment: Though nice answer, I am not any wiser... Let's talk about `InnoDB` engine only for now and let's focus on the situation described in question - INSERTing/UPDATing of **one row** at a time and logging this action - better with additional query run from application business layer or done by MySQL trigger?